# node pass value to result function

Tags: node.js

Here's how my code looks like

```
console.log(badgeList[i].id)  //will output the badgeList id

BadgeTriggered.findOne({ schoolID: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(schoolID), badgeID: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(badgeList[i].id)}).then(function (err, data) {
    console.log("get data")
    console.log(data)
    console.log("and show badgeList below: ")
    console.log(badgeList[i].id)  //badgeList[i] is undefined here
})
```

As you can see above, `badgeList[i]` is actually unavailable when I tried to print out the value inside the bottom console low. So how do I actually pass `badgeList` to the `findOne` result function?

Comment: That's weird. Global variables are accessible inside callbacks. I just tested it and I can't seem to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @fsociety my bad my bad. I edited the code for simplicity but I messed it up. Please see the updated code.

Comment: We use the phrase "as you can see" differently. `badgeList` is in scope in your callback, so something else is at play. Most likely `i` isn't what you think it is, which can happen for a variety of reasons, like your callback is running after your loop has completed, meaning `i` will be one past your array's length. Callbacks are *async* and will generally execute after the code that passed them has finished.

Comment: @imin do you mind sharing the wholde code like where badgeList is declared?